# sagemaker xgboost output to be JSON

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am new to AWS sagemaker and trying to do a simple test, where I am trying to call the xgboost model.

```
xgboost_container = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", 'us-east-1', "1.2-1")
```

Creating the model and endpoint:

```
from sagemaker.serializers import JSONSerializer
endp_name ="myendpoint"
acc_model = sm_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, 
                instance_type='ml.m5.4xlarge',
                endpoint_name=endp_name, 
                serializer=JSONSerializer(),
                deserializer= sagemaker.deserializers.JSONDeserializer()
                            
               )
```

Creating the predictor instance:

```
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer, JSONSerializer 

sess = sagemaker.Session()

payload ={
"var1":1,
"var2":2,
"var3":3,
"var4":0,
"var5":4,
"var6":0,
"var7":5,
"var8":45,

}

predictor = Predictor(
    endpoint_name=endp_name, sagemaker_session=sess, serializer=JSONSerializer(),
deserializer=JSONSerializer()  )
```

and then predicting:

```
predictor.predict(payload)
```

I want the output of the predictor.predict to be JSON format, however when I run this I get this.
[image]

What need to be done so that I can see the output as JSON?

PS: If I remove the deserializer I get the output as byte:
[image]

and if I change it to CSVDeserializer I get it out as:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the JSON Deserializer instead of the `JSONSerializer` for the `deserializer` option as shown below.

This implements methods for deserializing data returned from an inference endpoint. Documented [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/deserializers.html#sagemaker.deserializers.JSONDeserializer)

```
predictor = Predictor(
    endpoint_name=endp_name, sagemaker_session=sess, serializer=JSONSerializer(),
deserializer= JSONDeserializer())
```

https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/deserializers.html#sagemaker.deserializers.JSONDeserializer